# CSS can't align text with ::before and ::after

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to learn css and i've recently come across mix-blend-mode and i found really good code on codepen [here](https://codepen.io/ayausaspirit/pen/pVgXKb) , but when i try text-align: center;
only the h1 aligns.

```css
  div {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  h1 {
    font-family:"Yu Gothic", "游ゴシック", YuGothic, "游ゴシック体", "ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3", "メイリオ", sans-serif;
    font-size: 8vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.7);
  }
  
  h1::before {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    left: -5px;
    top: 0;
    content: attr(text);
    color:rgba(200,0,0,.7);
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  }
  
  h1::after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    left: 5px;
    top: 0;
    content: attr(text);
    color:rgba(0,200,0,.7);
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 text="BLEND-MODESを使う">BLEND-MODESを使う</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note: Before investing too much time with mix-blend-mode, make sure you're aware of how compatible it is with browsers: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mixblendmode. You could achieve a somewhat similar effect just playing around with opacity and z-index, which have universal browser support.

Comment: I was going to add a side note about mix-blend-mode too: It's somewhat esoteric. Even if it had widespread support, it's not something you'd use very often "in the wild." If you're learning css, this is probably a detour and not helpful to spend a lot of time on. You're kind of "in the weeds" with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `h1` inline-block and add `position:relative` so that the pseudo elements are postionned relatively to it (and not the div element) and then you center the whole h1 including the pseudo elements.

I have also simplified the code using `transform` instead of left/right

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Yu Gothic", "游ゴシック", YuGothic, "游ゴシック体", "ヒラギノ角ゴ Pro W3", "メイリオ", sans-serif;
  font-size: 8vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.7);
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
h1::before,
h1::after {
  content: attr(text);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left:0;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}


h1::before {
  transform:translateX(-5px);
  color: rgba(200, 0, 0, .7);
}

h1::after {
  transform:translateX(5px);
  color: rgba(0, 200, 0, .7);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1 text="BLEND-MODESを使う">BLEND-MODESを使う</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem with `text-align` that you're seeing is not related to your use of `mix-blend-mode` at all.

The css property `text-align` will align the text content within the available space of an element.

For block elements, it's straightforward usually, you get centered text. Here we see a simple example, the `h1` is a block element so it takes the entire available width, and the text is nicely centered.

I've added a red background so you can see exactly where the `h1` element is:

```css
h1 {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Test
</h1>
```

However, when you change the `position` property of an element, you take the element out of the *flow* of the box model. That means it does not factor into the position calculations of other elements, and it does not use other elements in its own position calculation, including width and height. Because of that, it loses the ability to calculate what "use the full width" means. Thus, a block level element begins to behave like an inline element, it's width is the minimum necessary to contain the content.

Note our red background now:

```css
h1 {
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Test
</h1>
```

The text is "centered", but since the element has the same width as the text, the effect is lost.

To see a box larger than the text with the text centered inside, you would either have to a) not use absolute positioning so it's back to the box model flow, or b) give the element an explicit width using the css `width` property.